# Maven unpack goal

Tags: maven, maven-3

I encountered a strange problem while using **Unpack Goal**. Here how it is.

I have the unpack goal defined only in the parent pom and I have multiple child test-projects(modules) which do not have unpack goal defined in their pom's

**Stage 1:**
I execute `mvn clean install -Dskiptest=true` to build all the modules during this phase
the unpack goal is executed and also I have a `version = RELEASE` specified for the zip I wish to unpack. During the unpacking phase version A.B.C is unpacked

**Stage 2:**
Now when I want to execute each test I execute maven by specifying the module which should be executed- Now why does maven again executes the unpack goal from the parent and also it uses a different version i.e. version P.Q.R is unpacked (which is the correct version)

Could someone throw some light on this issue.
Q1 - Is this the correct way of executing maven and if yes why is there such a difference during unpack goal

Comment: Can you please share the denpedency and plug-in declarations? have you checked your effective pom?

Comment: you can always check your effective pom via
mvn help effective:pom

Comment: Thanks for the answer will check the effective Pom.